# How to add multiple contents in a custom collection folder in Jekyll for Github Pages?

Tags: html, collections, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I do know that collections is an experimental feature in Jekyll, but since [GitHub tutted the feature](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0), I guess I could start using it.

I have a file structure like this:

```
site root  
 ├─ _portfolio
 │    ├─ project_1.md
 │    └─ project_2.md
 └─ /* rest of the Jekyll folders and contents */
```

This is what it looks like in Windows Explorer:

[image: Imgur]

This is the content for marble-run.md:

```
---
layout: project
title: Marble Run
---

This is Marble Run. All tests copyrighted.
```

And this is the content for pokemon-walking.md:

```
---
layout: project
title: Pokémon Walking
---

This is Pokémon Walking.
```

I have set `_portfolio` as a collection in the `_config.yml`, and have the `output` set to `true`.

```
collections:
  - portfolio:
    output: true
```

I used the following code to display the portfolio page:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="portfolio_main">
    {% for project in site.portfolio %}
    <div class="projects_container">
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ site.portfolio }}{{ project.url }}">Testing this.</a>
        <div>
            {{ project.content }}   
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`{{ site.portfolio }}{{ project.url }}` gives `/portfolio/{ title of the project }/`. As in, `/portfolio/marble-run/` for `marble-run.md`.

I expected to see two `Testing this.` links in the webpage, but I'm only seeing one.

[image: Imgur2]

My purpose is to create a collection folder that allows me to generate new contents whenever I put new Markdown files inside, just like what Jekyll does to `_posts` folder.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, been tackling this problem for at least 6 hours.

Collections do work normally in GitHub Pages.

To set them up:

1. In `_config.yml`, add this at the very bottom:

`collections:
    - my_collections`

Where `my_collections` are to be replaced with your collection folder name.

2. Do everything normally, according to the [official Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).
3. The only caveat is, you need to put the permalinks correctly, or you won't be able to reference the items in the `_my_collections` folder (after doing what the docs told you to do).

That's all I know.